# Included "foo_msgs/Foo.h" in pubsub/src/listener.cpp, but "catkin_make" shows error: "foo_msgs/Foo.h" not found

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i i am still getting error  foo_msgs/Foo.h : No such file or directory

i have a catkin_ws/src
this includes packages
foo_msgs  pubsub

foo_msgs contains   1) msg  2)CMakeList.txt  3)package.xml

pubsub contains       1) src 2)CMakeList.txt  3)package.xml

foo_msgs/msg/Foo.msg

int32 bar

its CMakeList.txt

////////////////////

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(foo_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS std_msgs message_generation)


add_message_files(
        DIRECTORY msg
        FILES Foo.msg)


generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS std_msgs message_runtime)
```

/////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
< package  >
  <   name>foo_msgs</name >
  < version>0.1.0</version >
  < description>The foo_msgs package< /description >

  < maintainer email="bar@baz.com "  >william< /  maintainer >

  < license>TODO</license>

  < buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend >

  < build_depend>message_generation</build_depend >
  < run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend >

  <  build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend >
  <  run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend >

< /package >
```

### ////////////////////////

pubsub/CMakeList.txt
//////////////////////

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(pubsub)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs )

find_package(foo_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)

target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(listener foo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

< package >

  <  name >pubsub< /name >

  < version >0.0.0< /version >

  < description  >The pubsub package</description >

< maintainer email="xyx@todo.todo >danish< /maintainer >
n
 <  license >TODO<  /license>



 < buildtool_depend  >catkin< /buildtool_depend >

  < build_depend >roscpp< /build_depend >

  < build_depend >rospy< /build_depend >

  < build_depend >std_msgs< /build_depend >

  < run_depend >roscpp< /run_depend >

< build_depend>foo_msgs</build_depend >

  < run_depend>rospy</run_depend >


  < run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend >

  < run_depend>foo_msgs</run_depend >


< export >

  < /export >
< /package >
```

///////////////////////////////////////
.......................................

i include          #include " foo_msgs/Foo.h "
in my pubsub/src/listener.cpp
but when i build using "catkin_make "
it shows an error   foo_msgs/Foo.h : No such file or directory
Please Help
Thanx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209506/i-include----------#include-%22-foo_msgs/foo.h-%22-in-my-pubsub/src/listener.cpp-but-when-i-build-using-%22catkin_make-%22-it-shows-an-error---foo_msgs/foo.h-:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [dash95](https://answers.ros.org/users/22478/dash95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't do anything in the CMakeLists.txt of your `pubsub` package which would add the include directory for your foo_msgs package to your include directory path.

Normally, when you depend on one package from another, you should use catkin to find it, the same you do for other ROS packages:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs foo_msgs)
```

This automatically adds the include paths for `roscpp`, `rospy`, `std_msgs` and `foo_msgs` to the `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variable.

You then add these include directories to your include search path using:

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Or

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # if your package contains an include directory that you are using
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dash95](https://answers.ros.org/users/22478/dash95/) on 2015-05-20**:
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS foo_msgs)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

I have included these to statements in CMakeList ofpubsub..................still getting same error ....... please help .
Thanks in advance